# Vector icon not show on Lollipop and above

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-vectordrawable

I have design a colored vector icon that use in my app.
Why that icon showed on pre lollipop version but not on above? Look:
[image]

This is my custom vector icon designed in inkscape:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:viewportWidth="19.6"
android:viewportHeight="19.2"
android:width="24.5dp"
android:height="24dp">
<group
    android:scaleX="0.04242505"
    android:scaleY="0.04242505"
    android:translateX="-7.118632"
    android:translateY="-3.364909">
    <path
        android:pathData="M230.3 140.13c1.03 -14.3 14.4 -26.3 28.6 -26.74 94.04 0 188.09 -0.01 282.13 0.01 14.64 0.75 28.57 13.6 28.64 28.59 -2.64 -13.86 -15.41 -25.41 -29.7 -25.54 -93.32 0.09 -186.63 0.04 -279.95 0.08 -13.87 -0.06 -25.94 10.61 -29.72 23.6z"
        android:fillColor="#37a6dd" />
    <path
        android:pathData="M197.33 175.95c-0.03 -16.86 15.49 -31.57 32.29 -30.93 113.53 -0.04 227.07 -0.03 340.6 0 16.89 -0.79 32.45 14.02 32.46 30.92 0.02 93.02 0.01 186.05 0.01 279.07 0.18 11.71 -6.79 23.16 -17.27 28.39 -4.71 2.56 -10.11 3.61 -15.44 3.46 -110.66 -0.06 -221.32 0.01 -331.99 -0.04 -7.15 -0.05 -14.66 0.73 -21.34 -2.44 -11.55 -4.8 -19.6 -16.9 -19.33 -29.44 -0.01 -93 -0.03 -186 0.01 -278.99m281.78 39.82c-8.16 2.55 -15.44 8.09 -19.7 15.54 -4.7 7.82 -6 17.47 -3.91 26.31 -0.04 1.65 -0.33 3.35 0.05 4.98 3.07 10.48 10.99 19.55 21.26 23.46 6.73 2.28 14.1 3.5 21.06 1.44 12.36 -2.47 22.86 -12.22 26.09 -24.42 1.52 -5.87 2.73 -12.37 0.26 -18.16 -1.19 -8.53 -5.35 -16.65 -11.95 -22.24 -8.88 -7.83 -21.9 -10.46 -33.16 -6.91m-118.14 46.9c-6.2 1.67 -11.71 5.68 -15.23 11.06 -30.6 45.42 -61.19 90.85 -91.79 136.28 -1.58 2.28 -2.72 5.14 -2.03 7.94 0.72 4.71 5.34 8.29 10.1 7.81 76.96 -0.12 153.93 0.23 230.9 0.01 15.37 -0.18 30.76 0.18 46.13 -0.02 7.03 -0.12 11.32 -9.32 7.12 -14.9 -20.51 -30.51 -41.07 -60.99 -61.61 -91.49 -2.19 -3.39 -5.07 -6.37 -8.59 -8.39 -9.92 -6.07 -23.93 -4.38 -31.89 4.19 -4.95 5.79 -8.56 12.57 -13.02 18.72 -11.97 -18.28 -24.39 -36.27 -36.52 -54.46 -2.72 -3.87 -5.05 -8.14 -8.71 -11.23 -6.68 -5.83 -16.34 -7.91 -24.86 -5.52z"
        android:fillColor="#37a6dd" />
</group>
<group
    android:scaleX="0.04242505"
    android:scaleY="0.04242505"
    android:translateX="-7.118632"
    android:translateY="-3.364909">
    <path
        android:pathData="M230.3 140.13c3.78 -12.99 15.85 -23.66 29.72 -23.6 93.32 -0.04 186.63 0.01 279.95 -0.08 14.29 0.13 27.06 11.68 29.7 25.54 0.14 0.76 0.41 2.27 0.55 3.03 -113.53 -0.03 -227.07 -0.04 -340.6 0 0.15 -1.64 0.31 -3.28 0.68 -4.89z"
        android:fillColor="#1078bc" />
    <path
        android:pathData="M524.22 244.92c2.47 5.79 1.26 12.29 -0.26 18.16 -3.23 12.2 -13.73 21.95 -26.09 24.42 -6.96 2.06 -14.33 0.84 -21.06 -1.44 -10.27 -3.91 -18.19 -12.98 -21.26 -23.46 -0.38 -1.63 -0.09 -3.33 -0.05 -4.98 2.47 9.95 9.48 18.66 18.75 23.05 12.1 5.89 27.51 4.07 37.73 -4.75 9.02 -7.38 13.6 -19.47 12.24 -31z"
        android:fillColor="#1078bc" />
</group>
<group
    android:scaleX="0.04242505"
    android:scaleY="0.04242505"
    android:translateX="-7.118632"
    android:translateY="-3.364909">
    <path
        android:pathData="M479.11 215.77c11.26 -3.55 24.28 -0.92 33.16 6.91 6.6 5.59 10.76 13.71 11.95 22.24 1.36 11.53 -3.22 23.62 -12.24 31 -10.22 8.82 -25.63 10.64 -37.73 4.75 -9.27 -4.39 -16.28 -13.1 -18.75 -23.05 -2.09 -8.84 -0.79 -18.49 3.91 -26.31 4.26 -7.45 11.54 -12.99 19.7 -15.54z"
        android:fillColor="#faef58" />
</group>
<group
    android:scaleX="0.04242505"
    android:scaleY="0.04242505"
    android:translateX="-7.118632"
    android:translateY="-3.364909">
    <path
        android:pathData="M360.97 262.67c8.52 -2.39 18.18 -0.31 24.86 5.52 3.66 3.09 5.99 7.36 8.71 11.23 12.13 18.19 24.55 36.18 36.52 54.46 20.46 30.74 41.12 61.34 61.86 91.89 -76.97 0.22 -153.94 -0.13 -230.9 -0.01 -4.76 0.48 -9.38 -3.1 -10.1 -7.81 -0.69 -2.8 0.45 -5.66 2.03 -7.94 30.6 -45.43 61.19 -90.86 91.79 -136.28 3.52 -5.38 9.03 -9.39 15.23 -11.06z"
        android:fillColor="#ffffff" />
</group>
<group
    android:scaleX="0.04242505"
    android:scaleY="0.04242505"
    android:translateX="-7.118632"
    android:translateY="-3.364909">
    <path
        android:pathData="M444.08 315.16c7.96 -8.57 21.97 -10.26 31.89 -4.19 3.52 2.02 6.4 5 8.59 8.39 20.54 30.5 41.1 60.98 61.61 91.49 4.2 5.58 -0.09 14.78 -7.12 14.9 -15.37 0.2 -30.76 -0.16 -46.13 0.02 -20.74 -30.55 -41.4 -61.15 -61.86 -91.89 4.46 -6.15 8.07 -12.93 13.02 -18.72z"
        android:fillColor="#ccd6db" />
</group>
</vector>
```

and also this is my object:

```
            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
android:id="@+id/reveal_gallery"
                android:background="@drawable/button_circle"
                android:layout_width="58dp"
                android:layout_height="58dp"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_gallerry"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
              />
```

any one help me?
thank you.

Comment: can you tell which imageview you are using i mean appcompatimageview or your custom

Comment: I'm using `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton` with `app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_gallerry"` attrib

Comment: it should work there should be some other problem i am also using same approach for vector drawables. Check your sdk version and build version

Comment: Min SDK is 16 and also support & appcompat Lib is 24

Comment: as you are saying everything looks good, need to check your code to figure out problem

Answer (score 1):

From the blog post here:

http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html

> ...when using AppCompat with ImageView (or subclasses such as
>   ImageButton and FloatingActionButton), you’ll be able to use the new
>   app:srcCompat attribute to reference vector drawables (as well as any
>   other drawable available to android:src):

So you would use:

```
<ImageButton android:id="@+id/reveal_gallery"
            android:background="@drawable/button_circle"
            android:layout_width="58dp"
            android:layout_height="58dp"
            android:padding="12dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_gallerry"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

Note that you do not need to use AppCompatImageView in your Xml as the support libraries automatically replace the system widgets with their AppCompat versions at build time.

Comment: This is my question: why vector show in pre lollipop version but no in above?

Comment: Most likely your vector is being converted to PNG by the build system.

Comment: Notification icon should be alpha-only images. Pls check out my answer.

Comment: They are not notification icons as he is using them in an ImageButton.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `ImageButton` instead of `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton` and I hope it should work fine with Lollipop and above.

Comment: Do you think this solution compatible with previously version?

Comment: As per [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html) ImageButton was added in API1. So i think it should be compatible with every version. Give it a try and let me know if it works.!!!

Comment: ImageButton will not support vector drawable on pre lolipop devices since earlier vectors doesn't supported by android

Comment: @alireza post your entire code for further investigation.

Comment: This answer is not correct. using the system ImageButton instead of the AppCompat version would have no affect at all. In fact, the systems ones are replaced by their AppCompat versions by the build system.

Answer (score -1):

Notification behavior is changed on Android 5.0. Check [behavior changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0-changes.html#BehaviorNotifications).

According to docs you have to use alpha-only images

> The system ignores all non-alpha channels in action icons and in the
>   main notification icon. You should assume that these icons will be
>   alpha-only. The system draws notification icons in white and action
>   icons in dark gray.

Note : a simple way to change image is just include background transparent inside your image.